# Defining __repr__ when subclassing set in Python

Tags: python, set, subclassing

I'm trying to subclass the `set` object in Python, using code similar to the below, but I can't work out a sensible definition of `__repr__` to use.

```
class Alpha(set):
    def __init__(self, name, s=()):
        super(Alpha, self).__init__(s)
        self.name = name
```

I'd like to define `__repr__` in such a way that I can get the following output:

```
>>> Alpha('Salem', (1,2,3))
Alpha('Salem', set([1, 2, 3]))
```

However, if I don't override `__repr__`, the output I get ignores the `name` value…

```
>>> Alpha('Salem', (1,2,3))
Alpha([1, 2, 3])
```

…while if I do override `__repr__`, I can't get direct access to the values in the set without creating a new set instance:

```
class Alpha(set):
    …
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name, set(self))
```

This works, but creating a new set instance for `__repr__` that will then be disposed of seems clunky and inefficient to me.

Is there a better way to define `__repr__` for this sort of class?

**Edit**: Another solution that has occurred to me: I can store the set locally. It seems slightly neater than the other options (creating and destroying something for every call of `__repr__` or using some form of string manipulation), but still seems less than ideal to me.

```
class Alpha(set):
    def __init__(self, name, s=()):
        super(Alpha, self).__init__(s)
        self.name = name
        self._set = set(s)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name, self._set)
```

Comment: The way you call `super`, you'll get infinite recursion if subclasses try to call `__init__`. The reason `super` explicitly takes a class is that it knows where to continue in the method resolution order (MRO). Pass `Alpha` (or if this is 3.x as the tags indicate, just use `super()` - it does the right thing somehow).

Comment: @delnan: Dang. Thanks for that. And there was me thinking I was being clever in getting to avoid specifying the class explicitly.

Comment: @delnan: For some reason, Sven Marnach briely tagged this question as Python 3.x. I'm actually using Python 2.6.

Comment: Regarding that last edit: I think you should avoid keeping a copy of the set in a private attribute because then you would need to keep it in sync. And to do that you would still need to copy every time you want to repr. For this approach you would need to probably forward all set method calls to the private set and use that entirely as your data.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I have something that gets you what you want, in addition to showing some benchmarks. They are almost all equivalent though I am sure there is a difference in memory usage.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

class Alpha(set):
    def __init__(self, name, s=()):
            super(Alpha, self).__init__(s)
            self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
            return '%s(%r, set(%r))' % (self.__class__.__name__, 
                                        self.name, 
                                        list(self))

class Alpha2(set):
    def __init__(self, name, s=()):
            super(Alpha2, self).__init__(s)
            self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
            return '%s(%r, set(%r))' % (self.__class__.__name__, 
                                        self.name, 
                                        set(self))

class Alpha3(set):
    def __init__(self, name, s=()):
            super(Alpha3, self).__init__(s)
            self.name = name
    def __repr__(self):
            rep = super(Alpha3, self).__repr__()
            rep = rep.replace(self.__class__.__name__, 'set', 1)
            return '%s(%r, %s)' % (self.__class__.__name__, 
                                    self.name, 
                                    rep)

def timeit(exp, repeat=10000):
    results = []
    for _ in xrange(repeat):
        start = time.time()
        exec(exp)
        end = time.time()-start
        results.append(end*1000)
    return sum(results) / len(results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Alpha():  ", timeit("a = Alpha('test', (1,2,3,4,5))")
    print "Alpha2(): ", timeit("a = Alpha2('test', (1,2,3,4,5))")
    print "Alpha3(): ", timeit("a = Alpha3('test', (1,2,3,4,5))")
```

Results:

Alpha():   0.0287627220154

Alpha2():  0.0286467552185

Alpha3():  0.0285225152969

Comment: Ya, I'd opt in for `list()` as it seems the most straightforward, but clearly it doesn't matter too much at all.

Comment: Im willing to bet, memory-wise that the first and second are less efficient since they are instantiating and throwing away objects. But thats just an assumption without actually checking the memory/cpu. The third example only gets a string and reformats it.

Comment: Possibly. I guess it's a question of, is `set()` or `list()` faster than the 2 calls of `Alpha3` (benchmark may be saying yes).

Comment: list() is more efficient than set() for sure. The string replacement is a little better than set() but gives him the exact formatting he wanted. So its a toss up

Comment: None of these feel quite right to me: creating and discarding instances will, I'm willing to bet, be much more expensive for larger lists, while string editing feels quite fragile and "unpythonic".

Comment: Regardless, +1 for a very complete answer and for including benchmarks.

Comment: @me_and - Thanks for the +1. Isn't a __repr__ method by nature a string formatting method? So it would seem to me that the 3rd option is reasonable, though instead of formatting your string from scratch you are just reformatting the superclass version.

Comment: @jdi: good point well made. I think that'll be the option I go for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't find any better way than to do this. I suppose it's better than throwing away a set though.

(Python 2.x)

```
>>> class Alpha(set):
...     def __init__(self, name, s=()):
...             super(Alpha, self).__init__(s)
...             self.name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return 'Alpha(%r, set(%r))' % (self.name, list(self))
... 
>>> Alpha('test', (1, 2))
Alpha('test', set([1, 2]))
```

Or, if you don't like the hardcoded class name (though it really shouldn't matter).

```
>>> class Alpha(set):
...     def __init__(self, name, s=()):
...             super(Alpha, self).__init__(s)
...             self.name = name
...     def __repr__(self):
...             return '%s(%r, set(%r))' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.name, list(self))
... 
>>> Alpha('test', (1, 2))
Alpha('test', set([1, 2]))
```

Comment: I'd not hardcode classname and use `self.__class__.__name__` instead (like me_and did)

Comment: @gecco: Personal preference. I don't see much point in not hardcoding it (unless you're going to have classes that subclass it), especially as some places still require it (super call). It's easy to change anyways. But I've added the non-hardcoded version as well as per request.

Comment: I agree with @JohnDoe. I dont see it as critical when you already need to explicitly use the class name for the super() calls. But yes it is a bit more dynamic.

Comment: @JohnDoe: I'm absolutely going to have classes subclassing this one, so using the dynamic name makes much more sense here.